# Return a string with all characters in upper case

Tags: .net, string, f#

I'm trying to write a function that returns a string with all the characters in uppercase using forward composition.

Here is my code without forward composition:

```
let toUpper s = String.map System.Char.ToUpper s
```

And here is my try using forward composition:

```
let toUpper2 s = s >> Seq.map System.Char.ToUpper >> Seq.map string >> String.concat ""
```

I made it work with pipe-forwards but can't get it to work with forward composition. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Function composition composes functions (hence the name), but you're trying to compose a function with a string for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This two are equivalent:

```
let toUpper1   =      Seq.map System.Char.ToUpper >> Seq.map string >> String.concat ""
let toUpper2 s = s |> Seq.map System.Char.ToUpper |> Seq.map string |> String.concat ""
```

but there is an issue with `toUpper1`. It is generic and that causes problems in ML languages:

> typecheck: Value restriction. The value 'toUpper1' has been inferred
>   to have generic type
>       val toUpper1 : ('_a -> string) when '_a :> seq     Either make the arguments to 'toUpper1' explicit or, if you do not intend for
>   it to be generic, add a type annotation.

so it requires a type annotation:

```
let toUpper1 : string -> string = Seq.map System.Char.ToUpper >> Seq.map string >> String.concat ""
```